# turtlebot_node/cmd_vel electric

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
In electric the problem that some nodes publish or subscribe turtlebot_node/cmd_vel or cmd_vel is supposed to be solved, but when I do sudo service turtlebot start the turtlebot node keeps listening to turtlebot_node/cmd_vel instead of cmd_vel.
I've been reeding the code but I can't see where's the problem, there's no remap and where the listener is defined it doesn't have ~ in front, so it's supposed to listen to cmd_vel. Actually, if I ran a roscore and then rosrun turtlebot_node turtlebto_node.py it listens to the correct node. How can I fix it?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12063/turtlebot_node/cmd_vel-electric/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2011-11-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-11-26**:
did you update your bashrc, are you actually running the electric code or are you still running diamondback. Try env | grep ROS to see what path you are actually running from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like your upstart scripts probably haven't been upgraded from diamondback to Electric. I suggest doing the following:

```
roscd turtlebot_bringup/upstart
sudo ./install.bash <iface>
```

where  is the name of your ethernet interface (usually wlan0 on most turtlebots).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2012-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1